# What's my mistake applying the Euler-Maclaurin formula?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation

I tried to calculate 
$$I = \int_{3}^{7} x^3 dx$$
using the Euler-Maclaurin formula. I figured the function $f(x) = x^3$ was continiously differentiable $2$ times, so my formula became
$$S - I = \sum_{k=1}^{2} (\frac{B_k}{k!}(f^{(k-1)}(7) - f^{(k-1)}(3))) + R_p$$
$$S - I = \frac{B_1}{1!} \cdot (f^{(0)}(7) - f^{(0)}(3)) + \frac{B_2}{2!} \cdot (f^{(1)}(3) + f^{(1)}(7)) + R_2$$
And calculating $S$ was rather easy ($S = \sum_{k=4}^{7}k^3 = 748$) so I continued
$$S - I =\frac{1}{2} \cdot (7^3 - 3^3) + \frac{1}{12} \cdot (3 \cdot 7^2 - 3 \cdot 3^2) + R_2 =$$
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot 316 + \frac{1}{12} \cdot 120 + R_2 = $$
$$158 + 10 + R_2 = 168 + R_2$$
And $R_2$ could be calculated as
$$R_2 = (-1)^{2+1} \cdot \int_{3}^{7} |f^{(2)}(x)|dx = $$
$$-1 \cdot \int_{3}^{7} |6x| dx = $$
$$-1 \cdot (3\cdot7^2 - 3\cdot3^2)) = -120$$
so $S - I$ became
$$S - I = 168 - 120 = 48$$
$$I = S - 48 = 748 - 48 = 700$$
However, after some further calculations and even checking it with WolframAlpha, I came to the conclusion that
$$\int_{3}^{7} f(x)dx = 580$$
which isn't the same as what I got. Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Comment: This may be because $p=2$ you chose is too small.

Comment: @Maam But the function $f(x)=x^3$ is only $2$ times continually differentiable, right? Since $f''(x) = 6x$

Comment: What you calculated is not $R_2$ but just a bound for $R_2$.

Comment: $f$ is a polynomial, hence it's infinitely often continuously differentiable. (And all derivatives from the fourth on are zero since the degree of the polynomial is $3$.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Then what value should I take for $p$? Or can polynomials simply not be integrated using this formula?

Comment: Polynomials can be integrated exactly with the Euler-Maclaurin formula (though it's typically used the other way round, integrating polynomials is dead easy, while the summation is more complicated; but for a short interval like $[3,7]$ the summation is quite easy too). Just take $p$ large enough that the remainder term vanishes, i.e. so large that the $p^{\text{th}}$ derivative is identically $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks a lot for your answers! Fun fact: the only thing $\lim_{p\to\infty}$ did was removing the error term, as $\lim_{p\to\infty}\int_{m}^{n}|f^{(p)}(x)|dx = 0$ and the series aren't influenced by any $p\geq3$. However, it did answer my question. Thanks again, a lot. If you want, you can answer the question below, since you've practically already answered it and that gives you the rep you deserve. Cheers.